# Is it possible to deploy my project to Smartface emulator via Wireless network?

Tags: android, ios, debugging, emulation, smartface.io

I want to deploy my application to emulator on iPad 3 (retina) without using cable. Is it possible to deploy apps to emulator over wi-fi?

Comment: @Robin , Smartface Emulator both works on Android and iOS, so "android" tag was correct for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smartface App Studio supports "Device Emulator" over Wi-fi , but because of perfoamnce issues it is disabled for current releases. You can check it from File Menu -> Project Details -> Debug / Emulator Settings.

USB Connection is always the best option in terms of performance and stability, in addition to this you can emulate your app manually with using Virtula Connection.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [TestFlightApp](https://www.testflightapp.com/). It will allow you to deploy builds to devices via internet.

Comment: Thanks @Novarg, but question was about Smartface.io's own emulator.